# FAT File Unique ID

Tags: arduino, fat32

I'm pretty new to working with file systems on an Adruino. Right now, I'm writing a function that will open a specific Fat file based on the file's 8.3 short file name (SFN). However, I've recently discovered that files in different directories can have the same SFN.

My question is twofold

1) Is there a similar file property other than the full file path (ie an index id, char[n] array, ect) that is actually unique between FAT files on an SD card?

2) If not, is there anything I can do to resign an SFN if it already exists on the SD card?

Comment: Are you using the  SD library (might we worth putting that in your question if you are) `SD.remove("example.txt");` will quite efficiently 'resign' your filename (and your file)

Comment: Nope. No other ID than the full file path, which is why you should always prefer working with full paths.